# What is the difference between a hash join and a merge join (Oracle RDBMS )?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, join

What are the performance gains/losses between hash joins and merge joins, specifically in Oracle RDBMS?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/optimops.htm#i76073

Comment: http://www.orafaq.com/node/1446

Comment: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/join

Answer (score 92, accepted):

A "sort merge" join is performed by sorting the two data sets to be joined according to the join keys and then merging them together. The merge is very cheap, but the sort can be prohibitively expensive especially if the sort spills to disk. The cost of the sort can be lowered if one of the data sets can be accessed in sorted order via an index, although accessing a high proportion of blocks of a table via an index scan can also be very expensive in comparison to a full table scan.

A hash join is performed by hashing one data set into memory based on join columns and reading the other one and probing the hash table for matches. The hash join is very low cost when the hash table can be held entirely in memory, with the total cost amounting to very little more than the cost of reading the data sets. The cost rises if the hash table has to be spilled to disk in a one-pass sort, and rises considerably for a multipass sort.

(In pre-10g, outer joins from a large to a small table were problematic performance-wise, as the optimiser could not resolve the need to access the smaller table first for a hash join, but the larger table first for an outer join. Consequently hash joins were not available in this situation).

The cost of a hash join can be reduced by partitioning both tables on the join key(s). This allows the optimiser to infer that rows from a partition in one table will only find a match in a particular partition of the other table, and for tables having n partitions the hash join is executed as n independent hash joins. This has the following effects:

1. The size of each hash table is reduced, hence reducing the maximum amount of memory required and potentially removing the need for the operation to require temporary disk space.
2. For parallel query operations the amount of inter-process messaging is vastly reduced, reducing CPU usage and improving performance, as each hash join can be performed by one pair of PQ processes.
3. For non-parallel query operations the memory requirement is reduced by a factor of n, and the first rows are projected from the query earlier.

You should note that hash joins can only be used for equi-joins, but merge joins are more flexible.

In general, if you are joining large amounts of data in an equi-join then a hash join is going to be a better bet.

This topic is very well covered in the documentation.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/optimops.htm#i51523

12.1 docs: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_join.htm

Comment: Thanks. 
"hash joins can only be used for equi-joins, but merge joins are more flexible."

Database System Concepts says both are used only for equi joins and natural joins.

   " The merge-join algorithm (also called the sort-merge-join algorithm) can be used to compute natural joins and equi-joins." See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50987379/when-to-use-merge-join-and-hash-join

Comment: @Tim Yes, quite possibly true for PostgreSQL, but not for Oracle. "The optimizer may choose a sort merge join over a hash join for joining large amounts of data when any of the following conditions is true: ... The join condition between two tables is not an equijoin, that is, uses an inequality condition such as <, <=, >, or >= ... In contrast to sort merges, hash joins require an equality condition. " 
 https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_join.htm#GUID-5FCD34FE-ED04-4AB2-BC90-9752FED94F4F

Answer (score 8):

I just want to edit this for posterity that the tags for oracle weren't added when I answered this question.  My response was more applicable to MS SQL.

Merge join is the best possible as it exploits the ordering, resulting in a single pass down the tables to do the join.  IF you have two tables (or covering indexes) that have their ordering the same such as a primary key and an index of a table on that key then a merge join would result if you performed that action.

Hash join is the next best, as it's usually done when one table has a small number (relatively) of items, its effectively creating a temp table with hashes for each row which is then searched continuously to create the join.

Worst case is nested loop which is order (n * m) which means there is no ordering or size to exploit and the join is simply, for each row in table x, search table y for joins to do.

Comment: If one were always better than the other, then the other would never be used, don't you think? I think the difference is more complex than this.

Comment: I'm sorry if you misunderstood me.  I was trying to describe the types of joins and why a merge join is best.  The problem is that merge join only works if you have sort order to exploit and a hash join is only more efficient when the joined table has a relatively small amount of rows in it.  Apologies if that wasn't clear in the answer.

Comment: Nested loops is the worst of course, when nothing else is possible.

Comment: Nested loops isn't always the worst because nested loop joins return their first results very fast (low latency). When you use hint first_rows chances are high that a nested loop join will be used because the hint indicates that you want low latency. Sometimes the user prefers high throughput, (batch process for instance), sometimes the user prefers low latency (in an interactive UI for instance).

Comment: I suppose if the result set is small thats a fair comment.

Comment: Overhead makes a difference too.  Nested loops perform well for small data sets because there is no overhead, just a per-row cost.  Hash joins may have a fast per-row cost, but there is an up-front overhead of building a hash table.