# Efficient way to find differences between two large groups in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, memory, hashset

In my case, I need to compare two large HashSets to find the differences using removeAll. To do that, I have to bring all the data from different data sources into memory then do the comparison. This creates Out of Memory issue when each HashSet may contain over 3 million records. Is there any ways or libraries that have less memory consumption  but also achieve the same results?

Comment: Split your data or use lazy initialization

Comment: is the data source a database?

Comment: How is the data stored? If it is sorted (according to some comparator) it can be done in a single pass using very little memory.

Comment: Another solution: More memory :D

Comment: What does a record represent? In addition to above comments, you might want to use POs (presentation object) as the type of sets (instead of heavy objects, e.g. with payloads).

Comment: The data is stored in different databases. My program retrieves the data and puts them into two HashSets which are initialized with the same Java class e.g. MyRecord. Then it calls `HashSet<MyRecord>.removeAll(another HashSet<MyRecord>)`

Answer (score 3):

Note that if the data is sorted, you can do it while streaming the data in a single pass, using a very low amount of extra memory:

```
i <- 0
j <- 0
while i < list1.size() and j < list2.size():
    if list1[i] == list2[j]:
        i <- i+1
        j <- j+1
    else if list1[i] < list2[j]: //i definetly not in list2
        yield list[i]
        i <- i+1
    else: // j is not in list1
        yield list[j]
        j <- j+1
yield all elements in list1 from i to list1.size() if there is any
yield all elements in list2 from j to list2.size() if there is any
```

Another alternative using hashing requires loading only one list (assuming here the data are sets, as mentioned in the question, so no dupe handling is needed):

```
load list1 as hash1
for each x in list2:
    if x is in hash1:
         hash1.remove(x)
    else:
         yield x
yield all remaining elements in hash1
```

Note that you can split the data and do the second approach iteratively if one list also does not fit in memory.

Answer (score 0):

What you need from your description is a hash join which is used in databases: [What is the difference between a hash join and a merge join (Oracle RDBMS )?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111707/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hash-join-and-a-merge-join-oracle-rdbms)

In short, to reduce memory consumption you could partition your data by a hash value. Very basic example: take a hash frame, i.e. hashes between between some values `h1` and `h2` from both sets and compare them. Then compare objects with hashes between `h2` and `h3`, etc. These `h1`, `h2`, ... `hN` might be easy to find just by doing

```
h[i] = i * ((long) Integer.MAX_VALUE - Integer.MIN_VALUE) / N;
```

or not - it depends on the data and on the hash function you have.

This solution requires `O(DB_SIZE / N)` memory and `O(DB_SIZE * N)` record fetching operations. So with N = 4 this would scan the database 4 times and reduce memory consumption 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

You can first filter out by non-common `MyRecord.hashCode()`s in a `Set<Integer>`
and then use `Set<MyRecord>`.

```
// Determine common hashCodes:

Set<Integer> hashCodes = new HashSet<>();
for (MyRecord record : readFirstTable()) {
    hashCodes.add(record.hashCode();
}

Set<Integer> commonHashCodes = new HashSet<>();
for (MyRecord record : readSecondTable()) {
    int hashCode = record.hashCode();
    if (hashCodes.remove(hashCode)) {
        commonHashCodes.add(hashCode);
    }
}
hashCodes = null;

// Determine common records:

Set<MyRecord> records = new HashSet<>();
for (MyRecord record : readFirstTable()) {
    if (commonHashCodes.contains(record.hashCode()) {
        records.add(record);
    }
}
Set<MyRecord> commonRecords = new HashSet<>();
for (MyRecord record : readSecondTable()) {
    if (records.remove(record) {
        commonRecords.add(record);
    }
}
commonHashCodes = null;
records = null;
return commonRecords;
```