# How does the optimizer decide between merge join and hash join?

Tags: postgresql, join, relational-database, query-optimization

Database System Concepts introduce several ways to implement a join operation. Two of them are merge join and hash join.

1. I was wondering when the optimizer decides to use a merge join and
   when a hash join?
2. In particular, from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1114288/156458

   > hash joins can only be used for equi-joins, but merge joins are more flexible.

   But Database System Concepts says both are used only for equi joins and
       natural joins.

   > The merge-join algorithm (also called the sort-merge-join algorithm)
   >   can be used to compute natural joins and equi-joins.
   >
   > ...
   >
   > Like the merge-join algorithm, the hash-join algorithm can be used to
   >   implement natural joins and equi-joins.

Thanks.

---

My question comes from PostgreSQL document, where there are two examples, and I am not sure why one uses merge join, and the other hash join:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM tenk1 t1, tenk2 t2
WHERE t1.unique1 < 100 AND t1.unique2 = t2.unique2;
                                        QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Join  (cost=230.47..713.98 rows=101 width=488)
   Hash Cond: (t2.unique2 = t1.unique2)
   ->  Seq Scan on tenk2 t2  (cost=0.00..445.00 rows=10000 width=244)
   ->  Hash  (cost=229.20..229.20 rows=101 width=244)
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tenk1 t1  (cost=5.07..229.20 rows=101 width=244)
               Recheck Cond: (unique1 < 100)
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tenk1_unique1 
 (cost=0.00..5.04 rows=101 width=0)
                     Index Cond: (unique1 < 100)
```

and

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM tenk1 t1, onek t2
WHERE t1.unique1 < 100 AND t1.unique2 = t2.unique2;
                                        QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Merge Join  (cost=198.11..268.19 rows=10 width=488)
   Merge Cond: (t1.unique2 = t2.unique2)
   ->  Index Scan using tenk1_unique2 on tenk1 t1  (cost=0.29..656.28 rows=101 width=244)
         Filter: (unique1 < 100)
   ->  Sort  (cost=197.83..200.33 rows=1000 width=244)
         Sort Key: t2.unique2
         ->  Seq Scan on onek t2  (cost=0.00..148.00 rows=1000 width=244)
```

Comment: In general, you don't use a merge join or hash join.  The database optimizer chooses among those and other algorithms (nested loop, index lookup, and variations on all of those).

Comment: I am trying to understand how the database optimizer chooses between them.

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/join/sort-merge-join and https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/join/hash-join-partial-objects

Comment: The memory requirement for a hash join is larger than for a sort-merge join. A hash join requires that all values of the join keys of both tables fit into memory, that is not the case with a sort-merge join if the values can be retrieved in a sorted way from an index.

Comment: @Tim . . . For that, you need to look into documentation and white papers specific to each database.  There are no general rules (apart from the applicability of a given algorithm for a given problem), because the choice is based on data statistics and hardware and software configurations.

Comment: Just to complement, this question is VERY database-specific. Each database has a different repertoire of available algorithms, and the way it chooses one over another is coded in the particular [version of the] optimizer itself. You would need to ask the PostgreSQL team itself for an accurate answer. Also, there's no guarantee it will/won't change in the future.